An open unit disk can be embedded into an area bounded by a curve
Let $\gamma:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$  be a simple closed curve, such that $\gamma|_{(a,b)}: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^2$is regular and smooth, and $\gamma(a) = \gamma(b)$. Let $U$ be the area bounded by $\gamma$. Show that if $|\kappa_r(x)| \leqslant 1$ for any $x \in (a,b)$, where $\kappa_r$ is the curvature of $\gamma$, then there exists an open unit disk in $U$.
I know that if $|\kappa_r(x)| \equiv 1$, then $\gamma$ is a circle of radius $1$, and thus $U$ is the open unit disk. But I don't know how to deal with the inequality since the curve can be any shape.
Update: I found this question and its solution in Anton Petrunin and Sergio Zamora Barrera's book What is differential geometry: curves and surfaces. It has a figurative name: moon in a puddle. There are also many other proofs: see https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.08455.

Maybe this will get you started: The breadth of the curve (distance between enclosing parallel tangent lines in any direction) is at least $2$.

The curvatrue may not be always positive for all x, so the distance between enclosing parallel tangent lines may be less than 2. There are conuterexamples.
